# Как изменить в редакторе Atom вид комментария в css и sass/scss файлах?

Tags: css, atom

Сейчас в css и sass/scss файлах код комментируется двумя слэшами. Как изменить на классический комментарий вида /* comment */ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментирование/раскомментирование [зашито в "ядро" Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/cbe8300f2aa561d61b98b41ffe217e4df18aa2c3/src/text-editor.coffee#L1376-L1377) и использует грамматику (CSON-файлы с правилами разбора для подсветки) конкретного языка, чтобы выяснить способ.

И **вообще-то в CSS нет однострочных комментариев с `//`.** Atom это знает и не нарушает. Когда включена грамматика CSS, Atom использует именно синтаксис `/*комментарий*/`.

Sass и SCSS это уже другое дело. Там однострочные комментарии есть и решать этот вопрос изменением грамматики не дело (может и возможно, но тяжело и ненадёжно). Есть пакеты, которые делают отдельное сочетание клавиш для "блочного комментария". Пакет `block-comment`, например, заворачивает выделенное в комментарий по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

А в качестве "костыля" можно переключиться в CSS и закомментировать в нём. Или даже собрать команду, которая висит на том же хоткее и, работая только в Sass/SCSS, переключается в CSS, комментирует/раскомментирует и переключается обратно.

Comment: На самом деле то, что закомментировано в sass/scss (комменитируется как раз двойным слэшем) не попадает в скомпилированный css-файл (проверил). Я-то беспокоился, что ИЕ такие комментарии не понимает. А в самих css файлах комменты классические, как раз вида /* comment */. Так что тут немного невнимательности с моей стороны:)

Comment: @Follower а, ну так на то они и препроцессоры, чтобы добавить синтаксического сахара :) А не понимать однострочные комментарии имеют право все браузеры так-то, их нет в CSS. Где они реализованы, они добавлены в угоду чужим вредным привычкам :Р